# What is difference between Shell(App.Path & "\" & "Hello.exe") and Shell("Hello.exe") in vb6

Tags: vb6, cmd

What is difference between

```
Shell(App.Path & "\" & "Hello.exe")
```

and

```
Shell("Hello.exe")
```

If I put Hello.exe in the program's folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First line will launch `Hello.exe` from the app folder. If it's not there, the call will fail.

Second line will try to find `Hello.exe` in several locations:

1. The directory containing the application EXE.
2. The system32 directory.
3. The system directory.
4. The Windows directory.
5. The current directory.
6. The `PATH` environment variable.

The call will fail only if `Hello.exe` is not to be found in any of them.

Related Raymond Chen post: [Your debugging code can be a security vulnerability: Loading optional debugging DLLs without a full path](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/11/10/10088566.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. What is difference between 1., 5. and 6.

Comment: @faressoft See the article. In short, current directory is any directory that happened to be set as current at this particular moment (can be a directory containing an opened document, for instance). PATH is a system variable that contains a set of paths (you can decide which), this often used to simplify launching programs deeply buried in various folders.